# Oracle CTAS randomly populating column with specific characters

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I am currently using CTAS to create and populate a table with random values.

I want to change the CTAS to add a new column work_days VARCHAR2(7). How can ALL 7 bytes of this new column, for all rows, each be randomly populated with either a 'Y' or 'N'?

Example:

YNYYYNY

Rewrite of the process to create and empty table first, utilize 2 loops then join everything together.

```
Create table employees(
 employee_id NUMBER(6), 
 first_name VARCHAR2(20),
 last_name VARCHAR2(20),
card_num VARCHAR2(10),
work_days VARCHAR2(7)
);

insert into employees.    (employee_id, first_name, last_name, card_num,  work_days)
with loop1(employee_id) as.    (select level from
 dual connect by level <= 50)
    ,loop2(b) as (select level from dual connect by level <= 7)

SELECT employee_id, 
CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,20)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Albert' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Tom' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Anna'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Ty' 
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Andy' 
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Thomas' 
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Alan'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Tara' 
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Cheryl' 
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Ed' 
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Steve'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Mel' 
        WHEN 13 THEN 'Micheal' 
        WHEN 14 THEN 'Ron' 
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Donald'
        WHEN 16 THEN 'Donny' 
        WHEN 17 THEN 'Racheal' 
        WHEN 18 THEN 'Debbie' 
        WHEN 19 THEN 'Madison'
        WHEN  20 THEN 'Danny' 
     END AS first_name,

 CASE  round(dbms_random.value(1,20)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Andrews' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Thorton' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Smith'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Jones' 
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Ott' 
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Stevens' 
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Feldman'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Stein' 
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Ross' 
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Eden' 
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Saltzman'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Kramer'
        WHEN 13 THEN 'Monroe' 
        WHEN 14 THEN 'Hanks' 
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Dunn'
        WHEN 16 THEN 'Dunbar' 
        WHEN 17 THEN 'Rucker' 
        WHEN 18 THEN 'Silverberg' 
        WHEN 19 THEN 'Daniels'
        WHEN  20 THEN 'Kahn' 
     END AS last_name, 
    
 dbms_random.string('X',        dbms_random.value(5, 10))  AS card_num,

      replace(listagg(CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,2))
                       WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'
                       WHEN 2 THEN 'N'
                      END,',')               within group (order by b)
             ,',') AS work_days
  FROM  loop1
    cross join loop2
 group by employee_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble to gain non-unique values, but this beast worked:

```
update employees set work_days = (
  select wd from (
    select level id, substr(wd, level, 7) wd
      from (select listagg(case when dbms_random.value(0, 1) <.5 then 'Y' else 'N' end) 
                   within group (order by null) wd
              from dual connect by level <= 7*50)
      connect by level < 50 )
   where id = employees.employee_id)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b77008a27cea86ff9facf620849a989)

Idea is simple, number below .5 becomes 'Y', otherwise 'N'. Then concatenate and cut this long string into 50 chunks.

---

Second, maybe simpler solution is `merge`:

```
merge into employees e
using (select employee_id, translate(dbms_random.string('U', 7),
                                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                     'YYYYYYYYYYYYYNNNNNNNNNNNNN') str
         from employees) r
on (e.employee_id = r.employee_id)
when matched then update set work_days = str
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f976e05636124045ef026d6500053c8)

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a single statement? Perhaps a loop within a loop?

Comment: I don't like the idea of hard coding values in more then 1 place if it could be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I added second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that converts the EMPLOYEE_IDs into binary values, and translate these into combinations of Ys and Ns.

**Function** (original [here](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Binary))

```
create or replace function dec2yn ( n number )
return varchar2
deterministic
is
  binval varchar2( 7 ) := '' ;
  n2     pls_integer := mod( n, 128 ) ;  -- allow decimals between 0 and 127 (we only have 7 days)
begin
  if n2 = 0 then return 'NNNNNNN' ;
  else
    while ( n2 > 0 ) loop
       binval := mod( n2, 2 ) || binval;
       n2 := trunc( n2 / 2 );
    end loop;
    binval := lpad( binval, 7, '0' ) ;           -- add 0 padding (lhs)
    binval := translate( binval, '01', 'NY' ) ;  -- translate: 0 -> N and 1 -> Y
    return binval;
  end if ;
end dec2yn;
/
```

You can use this in a virtual column (see [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4b59294509d6c920069079de6a6ec78)), or you can call it and pass the EMPLOYEE_ID in.

**Query**

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name,  dec2yn( employee_id ) workdays_
from employees ;

-- result
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
|EMPLOYEE_ID|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|WORKDAYS_|
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
|1          |Thomas    |Dunbar   |NNNNNNY  |
|2          |Micheal   |Stein    |NNNNNYN  |
|3          |Steve     |Monroe   |NNNNNYY  |
|4          |Madison   |Eden     |NNNNYNN  |
|5          |Albert    |Andrews  |NNNNYNY  |
|6          |Donald    |Kramer   |NNNNYYN  |
|7          |Andy      |Thorton  |NNNNYYY  |
|8          |Donald    |Ross     |NNNYNNN  |
|9          |Debbie    |Kramer   |NNNYNNY  |
|10         |Steve     |Stevens  |NNNYNYN  |
|11         |Micheal   |Monroe   |NNNYNYY  |
|12         |Steve     |Smith    |NNNYYNN  |
...
...
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions there all great ideas but this was just to generate sample data to test an application and  came up with a simple  solution and answered my own question.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for your feedback.